# How do I optimize my system to update my non-functioning IP address 162.?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ip, wireless-router, macbook-pro

Yesterday, my MacBook Pro connected fine, but today won't connect to the Cisco wireless router.  I'm running OS 10.6.8.  I don't know how this happened but I do know that my IP address is reading 162.... and should likely be a 192.... address.

Does anyone know how to optimize my system to correct for this IP address problem?

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: What happens when you try to connect? How far do you get? What's the first thing that goes wrong? Can you detect the wireless network?

Answer (score 0):

Addresses in the 169.254.0.0 range are [IPv4 link-local](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3927.txt) addresses. Are you sure it was 162 and not 169? A link-local address would indicate that DHCP is not available. DHCP is the service from your router which automatically provides an IP address to your computer. It can be very useful to [set a](http://www.hostmyapple.com/whmcs/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=3) [static IP address](http://www.remotemacserver.com/?p=5) while you troubleshoot DHCP.

Unfortunately, troubleshooting DHCP can be a bear. Start by putting yourself back on the network your router is on (the router is most likely 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) and navigating to your router's settings to see if DHCP is on. If you can't find your router at 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 by putting http://[ip address] in your browser, something is probably wrong with the router. Otherwise you're going to need help troubleshooting DHCP issues on OS X.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea APIPA was a Microsoft thing. Thanks Spiff!